# Yii Form birthday split in Day Month Year

Tags: php, yii

I would separate in the form(view) the birthday of the user in 3 different fields: day, month and year.
I wonder if I'm doing it right, and if there is an easier way to do this.

Is there a better method in performance? For all find it separates dates, although not necessary.

---

Model.php:

```
public $birthday_day;
public $birthday_month;
public $birthday_year;

...

public function afterFind() {
    $this->birthday_day = date('j', strtotime($this->birthday));
    $this->birthday_month = date('n', strtotime($this->birthday));
    $this->birthday_year = date('Y', strtotime($this->birthday));
}


public function beforeValidate() {
    if ($this->birthday_day  AND  $this->birthday_month  AND  $this->birthday_year)
        $this->birthday = new DateTime($birthday_year.'-'$birthday_month'-'.$birthday_day);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're only splitting the date into three parts for input purposes, one alternate option might be to use [CJuiDatePicker](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CJuiDatePicker) to allow the user to select a full date, for example;

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker', array(
    'name'=>'birthday',
    'model'=>$model,
    'attribute'=>'birthday',
    'options'=>array(
        'showAnim'=>'fold',
    ),
    'htmlOptions'=>array(
        'style'=>'height:20px;'
    ),
));
```

You can then format the result to your desired format for inserting into your database, for example;

```
...
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model=new Model;
    if(isset($_POST['Model']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['Model'];
        $model->save();
        ...
    }
    ...
}
...
```

Or to update;

```
...
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model=$this->loadModel($id);
    if(isset($_POST['Model']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['Model'];
        $model->save();
        ...
    }
    ...
}
...
```

In order to save the date as the correct format (i.e. convert from the user friendly format the CJuiDatePicker dd/mm/yyyy to your sql table format, most likely something like YYYY-mm-dd) then you could convert this before saving your model, like so;

```
public function beforeSave() {

    $this->birthday=date('Y-m-d',strtotime($this->birthday); // Or however you want to insert it

    return parent::beforeSave();
}
```

If you then need the specific day/month/year for displaying elsewhere in your app, you can either set them up like you have in your example as properties (`public $birthday_day;` etc), nothing wrong with that at all. Or if you don't want to convert the dates every time you call an instance of the model you could set them up a property, like so;

```
public function getBirthday($part) {
    switch($part)
    {
        case 'day':
            return date('j', strtotime($this->birthday));
            break;
        case 'month':
            return date('n', strtotime($this->birthday));
            break;
        case 'year':
            return date('Y', strtotime($this->birthday));
            break;
        default:
            return date('d/m/Y', strtotime($this->birthday));
            break;
    }
}
```

and if you want the day, just call `$model->getBirthday('day');`... or however you want to do it, that last bit's more personal preference!

Comment: Hi Stu. About using function getBirthday, when creating the form how it should be? `<?php echo CHtml::activeTextField($model,'???') ?>` And after form input, how i get the entries?

Comment: And using CJuiDatePicker, can you give me an example of the Update Action? For it has to load birthda from database, which is formated Y-m-d.

Comment: Hi, I've edited the answer to what should be a more complete example, I've not tested it, so be warned, it may need a little editing! Adding the model parameter to the widget should auto convert the date format and add it to the text field in the update form for you.